# Pass in param to 'Grunt watch' for directory

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

I use grunt to less>css, minification, and concatenation of my CSS and JS. I am wondering if it's possible to pass in a param when you type in "grunt watch" which would be the directory to watch. That way I can have multiple versions of a site running off the same gruntfile.

http://pastebin.com/b2FJ74SC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use node's [`process.argv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_argv) to get the command line arguments.

The code below can be called with: `grunt watch --dir myfolder`

```
grunt.registerTask('watch', function() {
    var args = process.argv;
    var folder = args[args.indexOf('--dir') + 1];
    console.log('watch folder: ', folder); // "watch folder: myfolder"
});
```